# BeanPostProcessor vs (@PostConstruct» and «@PreDestroy»)

Tags: java, spring

`BeanPostProcessor` дает возможность подключиться к жизненному циклу бина и взаимодействовать с ним по мере его обработки, а именно с помощью двух переопределенных методов дает возможность добавить какую-то логику после создания бина (но до его возвращения объекту) и перед уничтожением бина.
`@PostConstruct»` and  `«@PreDestroy»` делают ведь тоже самое.

Вопрос - в чем разница их использования и в каких ситуациях лучше использовать эти аннотации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы реализуете `BeanPostProcessor` для создания службы, которая применяется ко всем `beans` в контексте по мере их создания. `JavaDocs` показывает много конкретных примеров (`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`). 
Это средство наиболее полезно при создании собственной структуры поверх `Spring` или функций, которые применяются к подмножеству многих `beans` (например, создания своих аннотаций, которые будут работать в контексте спринга). Скорее всего, вы будете использовать существующие `bean` постпроцессоры, которые `Spring` предоставляет, но если по каким-то причинам вам нужно добавить свои тогда в этом поможет `BeanPostProcessor`. Кроме того, аргументами методов `BeanPostProcessor`, есть `Object bean, String beanName` и вы работаете с бином на немного ниже уровне, чем просто с полями экземпляра.

В то время как `@PostConstruct` и `@PreDestroy` это фактически спринговый декоратор для ваших экземпляров класса (объектов). Например: записать какие-то данные о состоянии объекта на момент удаления в лог-файл.

Answer (score 0):

Методы BeanPostProcessor-а возвращают бины которые после обработки методоами до и после инит попадут в контекст, тоесть идет донастройка бинов до того как они попадут в контекст.В то время как @PostConstruct это init- метод  BeanPostProcessor-а но в   BeanPostProcessor-е не описывается логика бина перед уничтоженим,тоесть то что делает анотация @PreDestroy